# Minimizing downtime in SaaS-multi tenant with separate database model web application

Tags: amazon-ec2, multi-tenant, amazon-rds, saas

We are having separate databases for each tenant which is creating a lot of downtime when we are deploying changes on cloud. The steps(in brief) what we follow whenever we have to deploy the changes on cloud are:

1. Put down the client site.
2. Take a snapshot of the current RDS instance(in case anything goes south).
3. Run the migration scripts(Changes) on each tenant database on RDS instance.
4. If everything goes well, then we make the client site live again.

Now the problem is, we are having around **250 tenants** as of now and the 3rd step which is **running the update script** is taking too much time which in turn increases the downtime. Any suggestions on how to improve this process or if we are suppose to do it in some other way. There is a clear lack of enterprise level expertise here on our end, so any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing anything about your application, here are some things to think about:

If your application would still have some value when running in a 'read-only' mode, you could limit the actual downtime by doing the following.

1. Make sure all of your RDS databases have a read-replica.
2. Set your application into 'read-only' mode (i.e. thru some application code).
3. Let your read replica catchup with your master
4. promote your read-replica to a stand-alone DB.
5. Run your updates against this copy of the database.
6. redirect your application to the new master.
7. create a new read replica from this new master
8. delete/archive your old database.

You still have to do all the work, and it still takes a while to run, but the actual downtime for the user should be minimal.

Comment: Thanks for replying, i see that restricting the write operations while updating can minimize the downtime and will see if there's a scope of implementing something like that for our CRM, still I wonder how giants like Facebook, Instagram does it without any noticeable downtime and without write restrictions. What kind of model they might be using to achieve this?